# jQuery/Javascript WON'T work at all... I'm lost

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason, jQuery and Javascript just won't work on my site.

See here: http://hellomynameisad.am/test.html

Can someone take a peak and let me know what I'm missing? I've tried numerous different snippers of jQuery and nothing seems to work. Thank you.

Comment: Its better if you add your code in question to make people understand the problem easily.

Comment: Hi, please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997) thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put it document.ready to make the html elements to javascript to execute or you can put your script just before ending tag of body.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/wAcYa/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#container").fadeOut(function() {
     $(this).text("World").fadeIn();
  });
});
```

**Edit:** I have found few other mistakes in html whichare as under.

1. There is no starting body tag.
2. Put script in between head tags or just before the closing of body tag.
3. Add type attributes in javascript script tag.
4. Its better to prefix url of jquery with http:

Change HTML

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.js"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js ">     </script>
      <title>Untitled Document</title>
      <style type="text/css"> </style>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#container").fadeOut(function() {
            $(this).text("World").fadeIn(); 
        });
    });    
</script>    
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">Hello</div>​
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There could be other possible solutions, What is wrong with my answer?

Answer (score -3):

Please Add this

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#container").fadeOut(function() {
        $(this).text("World").fadeIn();
     });
  });
</script>
```

part of your code after `</body>` ends and see it runs.

Comment: Any code that makes a DOM modification needs to go in some kind of ready block, you can't guarantee it's ready unless you do.

Comment: Writing after </body> clear that its run after that page is loded.

Comment: Your script requires a) that jQuery library has fully loaded and b) the DOM has loaded. It's bad practice to assume that so why it's best to put it in a document ready most of the time.

Comment: jQuery requires that you use the `ready` function for the most part.  Adding scripts to the end the file is bad practice.  The js should be added on an external js file.